# how to set the border in a DART TableElement

Tags: css, dart, dart-html

in a Grid example of 2012 the grid border is simply set with:

```dart
    TableElement _table;
    _table = new Element.tag("table");
    _table.border="1";
```

unfortunaltly border is no longer (running vers. 1.1.1) a setter in DART's TableElement class. Leaving it out results in a table without borders. 
How do I set a border?

Comment: _table.style.border = "1";

Comment: Does not work, alas. In Debug: _table.style.border = "0"; changes border to "0px". _table.style.border = "1"; changes border to "". _table.style.border = "1px"; changes border to "1px". But no border is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TableElement _table = new TableElement()
  ..setAttribute('border','1');

querySelector('body').append(_table);
```

or this should work also... I think

```
querySelector('body').append(new TableElement().setAttribute('border','1'));
```

Comment: The first (..setAttribute) works. Did not try the second one, as I already have a <div container> that holds my table, using ..clear ..addAll

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  TableElement q = querySelector('table');

  q.style
    ..border = '100px solid black';
}
```

Edit:

Ok I found out what's wrong, you are creating a new `TableElement`, not querying it from the dom:

```
TableElement _table;
_table = new Element.tag("table");
_table.style.border="100px solid black";
querySelector('body').append(_table); // add this line
```

Comment: you're missing the underscore - querySelector('body').append(_table);

Comment: added the line as indicated. Result: Uncaught Error: Class 'TableElement' has no instance setter 'border='.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'border='
Receiver: Instance of 'TableElement'
Arguments: ["1"]

Comment: @Martin Try `_table.style.border`.

Comment: I don't want to set the border style, I want to HAVE a border